# Drupal 7 theming : hook_theme or drupal_get_form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm wondering which is the best way to display a form on a page (for example : a register form for vip users ... and not in a block but as the main content).

The user.module *way* in user_menu (*hook_menu*) :

```
  $items['vip/register'] = array(
    'title' => 'Create new vip account',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('vip_register_form'),
    'access callback' => 'user_register_access',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
```

Or by creating a theme via use_theme (*hook_theme*) (fictive) :

```
$items['vip/register'] = array(
    'title' => 'Create new vip account',
    'page callback' => 'theme',
    'page arguments' => array('vip_register'),
    'access callback' => 'user_register_access',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);

function user_theme() {
  return array(
    'vip_register' => array(
    )
  );
}

function theme_vip_register(){
    return drupal_get_form('vip_register_form');
}
```

I'm wondering about this for theming purpose, because a designer will do the graphic integration afterwards.

Thank you for advices.

Comment: It was about best practice but it's very specific it's true. In the end, the designer prefers to have a declared template and that the theming functions return Render Array instead of rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an actual answer but I'm not quite sure what is your question at first place. 
Drupal customs #1: Never hack core!

As its name, theme functions are just to theme *something*. So you need the form built first.

```
$items['vip/register'] = array(
    'title' => 'Create new vip account',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('vip_register_form'),
    'access callback' => 'user_register_access',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
```

When a user accesses example.com/vip/register page, drupal_get_form function will be called with argument vip_register_form.

So now you need to define a function to return this (vip user registration) form.

```
function vip_register_form($form, &$form_state){
  ..your FAPI stuff here.
  return $form;
}
```

Now user who open the vip register page will see this form *instead* of the regular form. even password and username fields will not be available unless you add them. If you want to alter the existing form, just copy the menu hook to a new path:

```
$user_menu_routers = user_menu();
$items['vip/register'] = $user_menu_routers['user/register'];
```

Now you can alter your the form at vip/register page (which is same as normal user register page) using a form_alter hook. You can theme the form manually without affecting existing one as well.